# Wordpress URL rewrites on NGINX server (without htaccess)

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, nginx, redirect

I've recently learned that I'm unable to use the .htaccess file to redirect and rewrite url's on an NGINX server. I'm in the process of migrating a 20,000 page .html website to wordpress, and must preserve the permalink structure and add redirects to maintain the SEO.

All I am trying to accomplish are two things:

1. Add a 301 redirect to .html pages that will point them to their .php counterparts
2. Remove the '/public_html/' folder from the page URL
   [www.website.com/public_html/[affiliate]](http://www.website.com/public_html/%5Baffiliate%5D) => [www.website.com/[affiliate]](http://www.website.com/%5Baffiliate%5D)

I have been able to implement the 301 redirects via plugin for now, however I'm unsure how to go about removing the folder from the URL. I could place the affiliate folders in the root directory and not have to do this, but it will clutter up my workspace immensely.

This is my current attempt at rewriting the url (in site.conf.hbs  --- is this the correct file?)

```
    #
    # Rewrite public_html out of url when visiting affiliate pages
    #
    location /public_html
    {
        rewrite ^(/public_html/.*)/(\w+).php /$2.php last;
    }
```

Any help is much appreciated! The php redirect is working via plugin for now, but I'd like to just add it as a rule to get rid of the plugin if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: "is this the correct file?" - Depending on your Nginx installation there can be many files because includes are often used. Generally speaking, `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` is the main file and it often lists additional paths such as `/etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf` or `/etc/nginx/site-enabled/*`. So you will need to inspect your local config to find the correct file. You can also run `nginx -T` (with appropriate permissions) and it will dump out the entire config with includes injected which helps tracking things down.

Comment: To your question, have you seen this? https://serverfault.com/a/302512